How to style a TableView with rounded corners
I'm trying to style my tables to have rounded corners. I create and populate a TableView and set this one style for now:
table.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 20;");

and it looks like this:

How can I round off the inner corners of the TableView column headers and rows?

Did you see this similar question for [JavaFX] ListView ?

@Abra Yes. The selectors are different with a TableView. I cannot find any good documentation on the JavaFX selectors.

https://edencoding.com/style-tableview-javafx/

You can browse the JavaFX CSS Reference Guide for documented selectors and pseudo-classes for all built-in "styleables". You can also use Scenic View or the CSS Analyzer view of Scene Builder.

Basically the strategy is to not round the table itself but use a pane around the table with padding/margins.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

.table-view {
-fx-border-width: 1;
-fx-border-color: grey;
-fx-border-radius: 5pt;
-fx-background-radius: 5pt;}


.table-view .column-header-background {
-fx-background-radius: 5pt 5pt 0 0;
-fx-border-color: -grey;
-fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
-fx-padding: 5px 0;}


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
